# How to use node in /usr/local/bin instead of the one in NVM

Tags: node.js

Node is installed on my Mac at `/usr/local/bin`.

Then I installed Node Version Manager and started using it. When I type `which node`, I get `/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.6.0/bin/node` for example.

However, because of issues with other packages, I would like to use the node installed on my Mac (at `/user/local/bin`), not the one installed by NVM.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Set a symlink like so:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/node node
```

Here's a great answer about symlinks on Apple SE: [Symlinks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal)

Comment: It does not work. I get a message `ln: node: File exists`. I think it is because node already has a defined path

Comment: So the solution for trying to run the system-installed Node is to remove it?

Comment: No, `unlink` just removes the symlink to the installation, allowing a different symlink under the name `node`.

Comment: `unlink /path/to/old/node` does break the link, but I still cannot execute `node` because it is still looking for the file at the old path. I think I need to go to `npm config` and change the path there (and I am wondering whether there is a quick way to do this...)

Comment: You can use `npm config list` but I don't think npm has anything to do with it. Are you sure the link is broken if you can still execute node?

Comment: I saw a post on here earlier today by the creator of nvm saying to just use nvm and not symlinks.

Comment: From nvm maintainer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47734737/470749

Answer (score 0):

You can make nvm default to using the system Node with this:

```
nvm alias default system
```

Explained [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#listing-versions).

Comment: I get: ! WARNING: Version 'system' does not exist. default -> system (-> N/A)

Comment: @Bwyss do you actually _have_ a system-installed version of Node?

Comment: NVM doesn't let you setup a system version, apparently. See https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2708 - and they don't document that well in the readme.