# How to set $NODE_PATH when using nvm?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have installed node in my `ubuntu` system using `nvm`. It has been working smoothly until now, but one of my project neds $NODE_PATH set and `nvm` isn't setting it.

I would manually set it but I use multiple version of node. What is the best way to solve this.

I get following results from terminal commands

```
node -v
v8.9.1

npm -v
5.5.1

which node
/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node

echo $NODE_PATH
[nothing]

nvm --version
0.33.6

nvm ls
->       v8.9.1
         v9.0.0
default -> v8.9.1
six -> lts/boron (-> N/A)
node -> stable (-> v9.0.0) (default)
stable -> 9.0 (-> v9.0.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> v8.9.1)
lts/argon -> v4.8.6 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.12.0 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.9.1
```

I have read other similar questions and answers there didn't help. I have already tried commands like

```
nvm use 8.9.1

nvm alias default 8.9.1
```

These commands do not solve it.

Comment: Have you tried setting `$NODE_PATH` to `\`nvm which current\`` or `\`which node\``.This will set the path of node binary to the variable.But might not work with non-login shells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(nvm maintainer here)

`nvm` intentionally does not set `NODE_PATH` because it's an antipattern to use it - it allows you to `require` things that aren't locally installed.

You can manually set it yourself, after running `nvm use`, but it should not be needed at all. `nvm` doesn't provide any hooks to set it automatically (by design).

Thus, the best way to solve it is to refactor your project so that it no longer relies on this deprecated feature, that node itself isn't going to support with its native ES Modules implementation whenever that lands.

Comment: I have NVM and google cloud packages installed globally according to Google's instruction. Do you mean to refactor Google cloud? If not, `npm list` found the package, but running it in a different project still comes **Cannot find module**

Comment: Can you link me to these instructions? If they indeed rely on requiring global modules, then I'll reach out to them personally and ensure that's fixed, yes.

Comment: Just checked it, it doesn't ask to install global, it's me assuming "global" is like what we usually use, my bad.