# env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, nvm

env: node: No such file or directory

I checked if my directory for node wasn't wrong and it's fine.

I tried these following answers already:
1. https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3911
2. https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1702
3. [browserify error /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886217/browserify-error-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)

```
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ yarn init
env: node: No such file or directory
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew install node
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
acpica                   fantom                   lego                     qmmp
bat                      fn                       libdca                   rubberband
bazel                    fselect                  libpqxx                  ruby-build
cake                     fstar                    nativefier               saxon
calabash                 groovysdk                openimageio              shellcheck
cdrdao                   h2o                      pegtl                    sqlmap
cmake                    hadoop                   percona-server           teleport
conan                    heroku                   phpunit                  urh
convox                   jenkins-job-builder      pike
etcd                     jetty                    ponyc
exomizer                 jetty-runner             pygobject3

Warning: node 10.3.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0...
Error: Could not symlink include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
Target /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
Would remove:
/usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
/usr/local/include/node/config.gypi
/usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform-export.h
/usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
/usr/local/include/node/libplatform/v8-tracing.h
/usr/local/include/node/node.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_api.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_api_types.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
/usr/local/include/node/pthread-barrier.h
/usr/local/include/node/stdint-msvc2008.h
/usr/local/include/node/tree.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-aix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-bsd.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-darwin.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-errno.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-linux.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-os390.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-posix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-sunos.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-threadpool.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-unix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-version.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-win.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-inspector-protocol.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-inspector.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-platform.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-util.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-value-serializer-version.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-version-string.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-version.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8config.h
/usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
/usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit
/usr/local/share/doc/node/lldb_commands.py
/usr/local/share/doc/node/lldbinit
/usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0...
Error: Could not symlink include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
Target /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ run node
bash: run: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew install node --force
Warning: node 10.3.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew install node --rf
Warning: node 10.3.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew install -rf node
Warning: node 10.3.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ node install yarn
bash: node: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ npm install yarn
env: node: No such file or directory
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew install yarn -g
Warning: yarn 1.7.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.7.0, run `brew reinstall yarn`
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ brew reinstall yarn
==> Reinstalling yarn
==> Downloading https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.7.0/yarn-v1.7.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/yarn-1.7.0.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.7.0: 14 files, 4.2MB, built in 1 second
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ yarn install
env: node: No such file or directory
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ yarn init
env: node: No such file or directory
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
Password:
ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ $ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
bash: $: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ $ sudo brew install nodejs-legacy
bash: $: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ npm debug
env: node: No such file or directory
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ nvm debug
bash: nvm: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ npm --version
env: node: No such file or directory
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ nvm --version
bash: nvm: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ nvm install
bash: nvm: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node /usr/bin/node
ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:nomadcoin user$
```

Comment: You are installing node to your system, or nvm?

Comment: I thought node is already installed, and I tried to install nvm or yarn.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

- Try`node -v` to see whether you've installed node. I think your node not works.
- `nvm` is the environment managment for node. If you are using `nvm`, you should `brew install nvm`, and use `nvm install version-of-node-you-want-to-install` to install node, and use `nvm use the-version` to let node works.
- Whole install chain is:

  - `brew install nvm`, to install `nvm`, which is environment/version management for node.
  - `nvm install 10.3.0`, to install `node` and `npm`
  - `npm install -g yarn`, to install `yarn`
  - use `node -v`, `npm -v`, `nvm -v`, `yarn -v` to check if they all works.

Comment: Also useful: `which node` and if that's turning up nothing, then `find / -name node` for a full scan.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My node is not working. Also I tried following.....USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:~ user$ brew install nvm
Warning: nvm 0.33.11 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 0.33.11, run `brew reinstall nvm`
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:~ user$

Comment: OK assuming you are  using node 10.3.0, run `nvm install 10.3.0`

Comment: Sorry @TKJohn USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:~ user$ nvm install 10.3.0
bash: nvm: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:~ user$ nvm install 10.3.0
bash: nvm: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:~ user$ nvm use the-version
bash: nvm: command not found
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:~ user$ which node
USER-no-MacBook-Pro-2:~ user$                            I tried to type `find / -name node` then /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node
/usr/local/opt/node

Comment: Thank you @TKJohn !! It was done when following your steps. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this really helped a lot. thanks. I also used this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43037695/7377537 to resolve the issue

Comment: If you don't know which node version to install, try `nvm install --lts` to install the latest LTS version

Answer (score 23):

Perform the below steps:

1. which node
2. sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node (output of above step) /usr/bin/node

Comment: Although this works it doesn't seem ideal - having to update that simlink any time your node version is changed. Seems like something `nvm` should handle automatically...

Comment: I saw a post on here earlier today by the creator of nvm saying to just use nvm and not symlinks.

Comment: From nvm maintainer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47734737/470749

Answer (score 3):

For me I realized that hooks don't work when opening through the launcher.

instead I opened SourceTree through the terminal by running this command:

`/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/MacOS/Sourcetree`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu when trying to updating my `npm` version by using:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

I've solved by doing the same without sudo:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already installed nvm or node before and it worked, I would suggest to try to refresh your bash startup file. For example `source .bash_profile`

There are multiple bash startup file sometimes, you can check which one contains the nvm environment export setting to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

For some it may be as simple as forgetting to run

> npm use node

after an update. Or it was in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Node Version Manager (`nvm`) (without using `brew`)

If you see this when **starting a new ZSH or BASH session**, then you maybe have to check your `~/.zshrc` (`~/.bashrc`) file. `nvm` added some code for the environment at the end of the file. This should configure the default node version in your terminal.

But maybe you have already some code in your `.zshrc` file that depends on `node`? So move the `nvm` init code above other code that needs 'node'.